# Unwanted Wi-Fi Jamming by ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, wireless

I bought an ESP8266-01 module. I attempted to upload following code onto it.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println("I'm working");
Serial.println(millis());
}
```

Then I powered it and there was nothing in Serial monitor. Also my computer lost wifi connection. What's the cause of this error? How to solve it?

Comment: what baud rate do you have set in Serial Monitor?

Comment: Did the upload complete successfully? To upload, GPIO pin is required to be pulled HIGH; was it? A diagram showing how your ESP was connected for both programming and testing would help. About jamming the WiFi, could your PC see *any* WiFis? Do you have any other WiFi devices, and how were they affected? The more information you can provide, the better someone can help you find out what happened (or didn't happen).

Comment: @Juraj No matter which baud rate, there is nothing on the serial monitor.

Comment: @JRobert IDE said that it's uploaded successfully. Instructions stated that GPIO-0 connected to ground. Now I connected it to 3.3V, unable to upload new codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**:
I catched more details. ESP creates Wi-Fi network. It causes jamming.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "jamming"; if you mean your computer auto-connects to the ESP, you can disable auto-connect on your computer. There's no issue w/ having multiple networks in the same room, though :)

Comment: The only way I've found to interpret this that could make sense is that you created a network with the same SSID as your existing network, such that some clients connected to ESP8266 when they should have been connecting to the proper network.

Comment: @timemage, with that sketch? AP starts by default on esp. esp with wrong content of RF calibration data area on flash can disturb other WiFi networks. it usually adjusts after a few resets. but it is better to clear the RF calibration data.

Comment: @Juraj, I have no idea what you're talking about.